# "Keep it unchanged" vs. "Keep it constant" vs. "Keep it unchanging"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms, semantics

Using Google search, I found that the phrase "keep it unchanged" is very common while "keep it unchanging" is very uncommon and "keep it constant" is not so common. However, some [dictionaries](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/unchanged) shows that *unchanged*, *constant* and *changing* are all synonyms of each other.

So, are the meaning the same for 3 phrases above?

Comment: [Unchanging](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unchanging#google_vignette) tends to be used of things that, by their nature, don't change over many years - either natural things like mountains, or abstract things like the difference between right and wrong.  We wouldn't tell someone to keep something unchanging.

Comment: ...Kate puts it well. Immutable objects/situations are (relatively, usually) unchanging by their very nature; 'keep it unchanging' is akin to 'keep Mars in its usual orbit'. // 'Keep it constant' as Graffito says usually refers to a measure/parameter you have fair control over (temperature, speed, your weight(?!)). // 'Keep it unchanged' is a pretty close synonym of the far more common 'don't change it'. // Synonyms are words interchangeable with no or negligible change in denotation/connotation in at least some (rarely, if ever, all) contexts.  Different degrees of overlap in different cases.

Comment: *"So, are the meaning the same for 3 phrases above?"* The guidance is "In English, if the word or phrase is different, the meaning, or at least the nuance, is different."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unchanged** and **unchanging** are verbal participles functioning as adjectives; **constant** is purely adjectival.

The nuances are easier to see when used attributively:

His unchanged attitude was a disappointment. = His attitude that **had not been** changed **[by someone or something]** was a disappointment. (note the passive)

His unchanging attitude was a disappointment. = His attitude that **did not** change **[itself]** was a disappointment. (note the active)

His constant attitude was a disappointment. = His attitude that was **uniform [of a single type]** was a disappointment.

The pure adjective offers no agent, it merely gives a state.

Answer (score 0):

*Keep it unchanged* : Don't change anything from now.

*Keep it unchanging* : Continue to keep it unchanged (lack of change  in the past and in the future).

*Keep it constant* : the adjective would mostly apply to a physical measure, e.g. keep the temperature/pressure constant.